# Python - Pandas create column with np.where for multiple different values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id year Q
1 2017 1
2 2017 2
3 2018 1
4 2018 2
5 2018 3
```

And would like to get this create another column called D:

```
id year Q Desc
1 2017 1 '2017 first Quarter'
2 2017 2 '2017 second Quarter'
3 2018 1 '2018 first Quarter' 
4 2018 2 '2018 second Quarter' 
5 2018 3 '2017 third Quarter'
```

Yet np.where seems to only accept 2 parameter (if true and if false). So the idea is to have a np.where sentence that can deal with multiple possibilities

Comment: The multi-option version of `np.where` is `np.select`

Answer (score 2):

Roughly, using `np.select`

```
df['Desc'] = df.year.astype(str) + ' ' + np.select([df.Q==x for x in [1,2,3,4]], ['first', 'second', 'third', 'quarter']) + ' quarter'
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you just need to `map` your Q columns to `character` then using string sum

```
df['Desc']=df.year.astype(str)+' '+ df.Q.map({1:'first',2:'second',3:'third',4:'fourth'})+' Quarter'
df
Out[26]: 
   id  year  Q                 Desc
0   1  2017  1   2017 first Quarter
1   2  2017  2  2017 second Quarter
2   3  2018  1   2018 first Quarter
3   4  2018  2  2018 second Quarter
4   5  2018  3   2018 third Quarter
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` & `pandas.DataFrame.apply`:

```
d={1:'first',2:'second',3:'third',4:'fourth'}
df['Desc']=(df['year'].astype(str)+' '+df['Q'].astype(str)+' Quarter').apply(lambda x: ' '.join(d[int(i)] if len(i)==1 else i for i in x.split()))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id  year  Q                 Desc
0   1  2017  1   2017 first Quarter
1   2  2017  2  2017 second Quarter
2   3  2018  1   2018 first Quarter
3   4  2018  2  2018 second Quarter
4   5  2018  3   2018 third Quarter
```